# Find the title and artist of this song

Tags: cipher

Below, I've used this alphabet:

[image]

to encode the first eight lines of a song. Find the title and artist.

4c4a’3h4a 3b1d1f3g2a 2e1d 4c3a1b2e 3a2b2b 3g1b3d3e2e
1e3e4a’1e 3b1d1f3g2a 2e1d 3h1f3g 3a4b1d3f
1b3g2f4a1e2e4a2a 4a3g1d1f3d3e 1b3g 1b2e 3a3g3i3e1d4c,
2e1d 4a3a1a3e 3e1b1e 1d4c3g…
2e3e4a 3d3a3h2a4a3g 3g4a4a2a1e 1e1d3h2e1b3g3d 1d1f2e
1e3e4a 1a1f3h2b1e 3e4a3h 2b1b2c1e 1d3g 2e3e4a 3b1d4c
3a3g2a 1b 2a1d3g’2e 3f3g1d4c 1b3c 1b’4b 2a4a3a2a 1d3h 3g1d2e
2e1d 3a3g3i1d3g4a…

Hint #1:

> It was on the radio, so it's fairly mainstream.

Hint #2:

> It was released in 2010.

Hint #3:

> The apostrophes, commas, and ellipses are not encoded.

Comment: I don't understand , what do you mean you used that alphabet? There are number too.

Comment: @The Emperor of Ice Cream It's a clue, but I cannot explain it, or it might give away too much information.

Comment: what is an ellipse?

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream An ellipsis (plural ellipses) is the "..." symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title and artist are:

> **[The High Road](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/brokenbells/thehighroad.html)** by the "Broken Bells"

The encryption is:

> Each pair of characters represents a letter of the alphabet.
>  The cipher characters below are followed by the plain text characters in the same order.
>
>  1a 1b 1d 1e 1f 2a 2b 2c 2e 2f 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f 3g 3h 3i 4a 4b 4c
>
>  C I O S U D L P T V A B F G H K N R Y E M W

Comment: I have verified your solution. The code is a simple substitution code (1a=C, 1b=I, 1d=O, 1e=S, 1f=U, etc). The code looks totally arbitrary, and I fail to see a pattern in it.

Comment: You got the correct answer. I wish now that I had also asked what the pattern was, because that is the more interesting thing, I think. I was hoping that the person who got the solution would get it by finding the pattern, and using the clue that I gave about that exact alphabet.