# What was the encryption mapping?

Tags: cipher

In this [Recent Question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10265/find-the-title-and-artist-of-this-song), what was the encryption mapping?

In other words, how did each letter map to its 2-digit counterpart?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: (I upvoted, but) maybe you should have edited your previous question instead of posting a new one?

Comment: @randal'thor the question had already been answered, correctly, so i thought it better to ask a new question, rather than to say something lame like, "yeah, ok, but what about this other question then?"

Comment: @Len Well, making the encryption mapping easy for everyone to guess is not usually one of the goals. the more subjective, the better in most cases. In the encryption question figuring out the mapping could be (and was) bypassed by using English frequency distributions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The encryption mapping was done by:

> dividing the alphabet into **4 groups of letters** based on the **number of strokes** that could be used to hand-print each letter (from 1 to 4 strokes). The letters in each group are in alphabetical order.
>
>  If this is the correct answer, it should be noted that there is no standard method of hand-printing the English alphabet, although this [wikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Letters-of-the-English-Alphabet) does describe the use of a similar number of strokes. There are many guidelines for using other methods.
>
>  [image: CodeMap]

Comment: Yes, excellent work.